# Customizing CardViews to match a mockup

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a UI mockup that i need to achieve which contains `cardViews`. I managed to create the top part with the title etc. but i can't make `cardViews` work. I've never worked with these and i tried doing something like what you can see below but obviously it looks nothing like it.

my attempt:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="TextView" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

the UI mockup:

[image: final image]

I can't seem to make the `ImageView`'s background i have as a placeholder fill the top part of the `cardView` while showing the `TextView` below it at the same time. I've tried changing the `cardView`'s `layout width` and `layout height` values to both `match_parent` and `wrap_content` but that didn't help. I tried that for the `imageView` itself too but no luck either. I also can't really see the `CardView` itself in the layout preview which makes it impossible to work on.

How should i go about designing it?

what my current layout looks like:

[image: current]

Comment: Do you really have to create it using a `HorizontalScrollView`? IMO, using a `RecyclerView` would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this layout should work for you.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/map_loot_tier" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="Beach name"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:text="Location of the beach" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/map_loot_tier" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="Beach name"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:text="Location of the beach" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

After creating it, don't forget to test it on real device instead of the Android Studio preview.